# Can I set the Java GC log file ( -Xloggc:) at runtime?

Tags: java

Can I set the Java GC log file ( -Xloggc:) at runtime? and not as a VM options?

I just want to set the GC log file from my application config file and not the the vm options

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change properties that doesn't start with `D` at runtime, so in this case you can't. It is not possible to change the Garbage collector log at runtime.

Comment: The GC log file is not expensive, we keep it running on our production servers. The best thing about the log is that you can grep for long full collections to find out if you've allocated enough memory. I recommend looking at http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow for some discussion of the GC.